# React modal component receiving same class

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a react Modal component that I have made. I can pass a prop that makes it full screen or define a width. It all works fine, but i'm having an issue reusing it when the first modal is open. The 2nd component takes the same class as the 1st, so it makes the max-width 100%.

For example, I want to have a full screen modal, and show a 2nd modal at 50% size on top when i click a link.

I am using styled components which i think is where the issue may be happening. Im just not sure how to approach it.

Modal component:

```
<ModalContainer visible={visible} fullScreen={fullScreen}>
    <ModalDialog role="dialog" width={width}>
       <ModalBody>{children}</ModalBody>
    </ModalDialog>
</ModalContainer>
```

Styles

```
export const ModalDialog = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  max-width: ${({ width }) => width};
`;


export const ModalContainer = styled.div`
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;

  ${({ visible }) =>
    visible &&
    css`
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      display: flex;
    `}

   ${({ fullScreen }) =>
    fullScreen &&
    css`
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: none;

      ${ModalDialog} {
        box-shadow: none;
        max-width: 100%;
      }
   
    `}
`}
```

The class of the first modal for dialog is what is also being used for the 2nd even though that does not have the full screen prop.